# How to make plt.canvas.draw() update work, if first image is empty?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The code below do show just empty image all the time

```
%matplotlib tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import time
from copy import deepcopy
pp.close('all')
img1 = np.zeros((400,400), dtype = np.uint8)
new_list = []
for i in range(100):
    new_list.append(deepcopy(img1).astype(np.uint8))
    new_list[-1][i:i+100,i:i+100] = 255
    if i == 0:
        new_list[-1][i:i+100,i:i+100] = 0 
        #new_list[-1][i,i] = 1 
if True:
    fig,ax = pp.subplots(1,1)
    image = ax.imshow(new_list[0],animated=True)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    start = time.time()
    tic = start
    for i in range(100):
        if not(i % 10):
            toc = time.time()
            tic = time.time()
        image.set_data(new_list[i])
        fig.canvas.draw()
```

However, if I just uncomment single line

```
new_list[-1][i,i] = 1
```

or start with any other non-zero image,like

```
image = ax.imshow(np.eye(400, dtype = np.uint8),animated=True)
```

figure updates as it should - showing moving 100x100 square. My question is following: why does it happen and is there any way to make figure update work if start with zero-only image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial array in the image is all zeros, the image will be single colored, even if updated. To prevent this you may set a normalization for the image which shall then be used throughout. In this case it seems the largest value is 255, hence

```
ax.imshow(..., vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

In your case it might make sense to use a `FuncAnimation`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from copy import deepcopy


img1 = np.zeros((400,400), dtype = np.uint8)
new_list = []
for i in range(100):
    new_list.append(deepcopy(img1).astype(np.uint8))
    new_list[-1][i:i+100,i:i+100] = 255
    if i == 0:
        new_list[-1][i:i+100,i:i+100] = 0 
        new_list[-1][i,i] = 1 

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
image = ax.imshow(new_list[0],animated=True, vmin=0, vmax=255)

def animate(i):
    image.set_data(new_list[i])

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=10)
plt.show()
```